# Setting maven to have a framework and other projects that use it

Tags: java, maven, testing, dependencies

I created a Maven project that i should use as a framework. This framework has some dependencies:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>SeleniumJavaFramework</groupId>
    <artifactId>SeleniumJavaFramework</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-alpha-6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I'd like to create other Maven projects, separated from the framework project, that will have their own pom.xml with the framework dependency.
If possible, they should inherit dependencies from the framework project.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>RicercaGoogle</groupId>
    <artifactId>RicercaGoogle</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>TestOne</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>SeleniumJavaFramework</groupId>
            <artifactId>SeleniumJavaFramework</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>patofmyjar.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Unfortunately I don't know where to start with the maven settings. I'm not even sure if the pom files are correct. I only know that i can't simply put the jar dependency into the test project and run it. Can you help me out?

Thank you

Comment: I _think_ what you're looking for is a _parent POM_. I'll note that the configuration (particularly Java 7) is seriously out of date and suggest modernizing before continuing.

Comment: can you help me with parent POM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working at single project, you can create a parent pom that include your TestOne app and Framework as two modules, so you'll have 3 poms (search for maven multimodule project). If your framework is a library for different projects, you need a repository (ie nexus), where your Framework can be deployed to. Then you can use it as a dependency in other projects (dependencies of Framework will be included automatically)

Comment: If your framework is a library for different projects: yes it is, but at the moment i do not have a repository, so it has to be a jar file.

Comment: If Framework is a library, there is no sense to make a parent pom. Do 'mvn install' on the Framework project to store it in local repository (<user.home>/.m2). Then the TestOne project can see it as a dependency. Of coarse, this will work on your machine only.

Comment: I did as you say and i got a jar inside a the target folder, however the test project is unable too detect framework classes

Comment: Check the local repo: <user.home>/.m2/repository/SeleniumJavaFramework/SeleniumJavaFramework/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

Comment: And remove the <scope> and <systemPath> tags from dependency

Comment: And remove the <scope> and <systemPath> tags from dependency:

Missing artifact SeleniumJavaFramework:SeleniumJavaFramework:jar:0.1.1-SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to follow the maven official guide for learning how inheritance works in maven and adapt this to your logic:

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Inheritance

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer.

Comment: Possibly you are right, but as the user is asking for a way to inherit dependencies, this is the way, so an answer itself

Comment: Thank you, luckily I solved the problem. I didn't need a parent pom for this kind of project, i just had to change classes directories.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that my classes where in the wrong folders.
They were in `src/test/java` while they had to be in `src/main/java`.
Also in the test project pom i removed scope and systemPath as suggested by Andrew Fomin

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>SeleniumJavaFramework</groupId>
            <artifactId>SeleniumJavaFramework</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
```

I had an error

```
Missing artifact SeleniumJavaFramework:SeleniumJavaFramework:jar:0.1.1-SNAPSHOT
```

because, as you can see, version was wrong.

Thank you all